# Multiple JavaScript timeout popups that are only displayed if previous popup has been closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, settimeout

I have a page that times out a session after an hour. I need to display a popup alert at 45 minutes then every minute from 50 - 60 using JavaScript or jQuery (I don't know jQuery, but it's available). At the 60 minute mark I need a final message informing the user the page will refresh. The part that gets me is if one popup is displayed, no others should be until it is closed, except for the final. i.e. ff the 10 minute popup is displayed but not closed for 2 minutes, the 9 and 8 minute popups should never display but the 7 minute should.

So far I have come up with a function that is called on page load, but it is both ugly and doesn't work:

```
// Alerts starting at 45 minutes into session, then from 10 - 1, and a final alert
    var timerMultiplier = 10000; //used so I can change times in testing
    var timeoutAlertAcknowledged = true; //a flag I've tried using to know when a box has been closed
    function setTimeoutAlerts(){
        if(document.getElementById("$!arsTO.getConstantValue('FIELD_NAME_ROW_COUNT')").value > 0){
            var sessionWarningTime15=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',15, sessionWarningTime15)}, 270*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime10=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',10, sessionWarningTime10)}, 300*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime9=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',9, sessionWarningTime9)}, 306*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime8=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',8, sessionWarningTime8)}, 312*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime7=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',7, sessionWarningTime7)}, 318*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime6=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',6, sessionWarningTime6)}, 324*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime5=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',5, sessionWarningTime5)}, 330*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime4=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',4, sessionWarningTime4)}, 336*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime3=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',3, sessionWarningTime3)}, 342*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime2=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',2, sessionWarningTime2)}, 348*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionWarningTime1=setInterval(function () {myTimer('warning',1, sessionWarningTime1)}, 354*timerMultiplier);
            var sessionEndTime=setInterval(function () {myTimer('timesUp',0, sessionEndTime)}, 360*timerMultiplier);
        }
    }

    //Create popup alerts
    function myTimer(type, time, timerVariable) {
        clearInterval(timerVariable); //clear current timer variable so it only occurs once
        if(type == 'warning' && timeoutAlertAcknowledged == true){
            timeoutAlertAcknowledged = false;
            alert("WARNING: Your session will expire in "+ time +" minutes.");
        }
        else if(type == 'timesUp'){
            alert("The session has expired. The page will now be refreshed.");
            pageRefreshMethod();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) use setTimeout 2. set the next timeout inside the function you call with the timeout 3) do NOT use alert but show and hide an absolutely positioned or a position:fixed div or even a dialog that can be moved or dismissed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the working prototype that I ended up working off of for my final version (thanks to anders):

```
var alertTimes = [10, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]; 
var startTime = new Date();
function setNextTimeout() {
       var currentTime = new Date();
       var elapsedTime = (currentTime - startTime)/1000;
       var tempTime;
       // Find the index i of the next alertTimes.
       var i;
       for(i=0; i<alertTimes.length; i++){
           tempTime = alertTimes[i];
           if(tempTime >= elapsedTime) break;
       }
       var delay = 0;
       if(i < alertTimes.length){
           delay= (alertTimes[i] - elapsedTime)*1000;

       }
       if(delay != 0){
           setTimeout(function(){showPopUp(alertTimes[i]);}, delay);
       }
       else if(i >= alertTimes.length){
           setTimeout(function(){showPopUp("FINAL");}, delay);
       }
}

function showPopUp(time) {
    alert("It has been "+time+" sedconds.");
    if(time != "FINAL"){
        setNextTimeout();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Approach 1: One timeout at a time

One way to do this is to only set one timeout at a time. The idea is to call a function (`setNextTimeout`) every time the user closes a popup. It then checks what time it is, and finds the time the next popup should be displayed from an array of predefined times. The difference between those are the delay you want until your next popup.

Please note that I have not tested this code, and you might need to fix a few mistakes and adapt it to your exact circumstances. So it is not copy-paste ready.

```
//Define when we want the pop up to appear.
var popup_times = [45, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
//Save the start time for future reference.
var start_time = new Date();
//Start the whole thing off.
setNextTimeout();

function setNextTimeout() {
   //Calculate the number of minutes that has passed.
   var current_time = new Date();
   var elapsed_time = (current_time - start_time) / (60 * 1000);
   //Find the index i of the next popup_times.
   var i;
   for(i=0; i<popup_times.length; i++)
      if(popup_times[i] >= elapsed_time) break;
   //Calculate the delay until the next popup in milliseconds.
   //If we are past the last popup time, we should do something immediately.
   //Hence the i < popup_times.length ? ... : 0 part.
   var delay = i < popup_times.length ? (popup_times[i] - elapsed_time) * 60 * 1000 : 0;
   //Set the timeout.
   //Replace showPopUp with whatever function you use to handle the pop up.
   //Might want to pass some parameters as well, for instance to specify for what time the popup is.
   setTimeout(showPopUp, delay);
}
```

Finally, you need to make sure that when the user closes the popup, the function `setNextTimeout()` is called again to close the loop. If you are just using an alert, it could look like this:

```
function showPopUp() {
    alert("Message!");
    //This will only run once the alert is closed.
    setNextTimeout();
}
```

## Approach 2: All the timeouts at once

An alternative, that will not work if you use alert for the popups, is to set all the timeouts at once. Instead of an alert you will need to use a div with an absolute position or some similar technique. That could look like this:

```
//Define when we want the pop up to appear.
var popup_times = [45, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]
//Keep a flag to track if the popup is open.
var popup_open = false;

//Set all the timeouts.
for(var i=0; i<popup_times.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(showPopUp, popup_times[i] * 60 * 1000);
}

//A function to show the popup.
function showPopUp() {
    //Only show the popup if one isn't already open.
    if(!popup_open) {
        //Now one is open.
        popup_open = true;
        //Put code to open the popup here.
        //Since it is a separate problem I will not cover it here.
        //Just google for how to do a JavaScript popup.
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to make sure that when the popup is closed, `popup_open` is set to `false` again.